# Remove Already Uploaded File in Scala Play-Bootstrap Form

Tags: scala, twitter-bootstrap-3, playframework

I have a working b3 play framework form with file upload. The only issue is I cannot see anywhere in the documentation to remove an already uploaded file. Ideally there would just be a "remove" type button by the file upload that could remove the already uploaded file before form submission.

My current form is below. Any help or suggestions on solving this are more than welcome.

Thank you

```
        @b3.form(routes.SettingsController.submitEditProfile, 'enctype -> "multipart/form-data") {
        @CSRF.formField

        @b3.text(userForm("displayName"), '_label -> "Display name")

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="settingsImage">Settings Image</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @user.settingsImage.fold {
                    <p>@Messages("has.no.image")</p>
                }{ c =>
                    <p>@Messages("has.image")</p>
                    @c.artifacts.find(a => a.label == "small" && a.url.nonEmpty).map{ ca =>
                        <img src="@ca.url" @includes.artifactDimensions(ca) /></a>
                    }
                }
                <input type="file" name="settingsImage" />
            </div>
        </div>

        @b3.free('_id -> "idFormGroup") {
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">@Messages("update")</button>
            <a class="btn btn-default" href="@routes.SettingsController.settings()">@Messages("cancel")</a>
        }
```